# R: Efficiency concerns when dynamically updating matrix without preallocation

Tags: r, performance, bigdata

I am extracting data from an API which I stack in an array by means of a `for` loop. I use a `for` loop over `plyr` because my code is not sufficiently robust yet to run without errors, such that for now I can restart the `for` loop manually or with a `tryCatch()`.  Working example (for sake of exposition, without API call but with some simple computations):

```
x <- 1:10000
mydata <- NULL

for(i in 1:length(x)){

  y = x[i]
  x1 = y*2
  x2 = y*3
  x3 = y*4

mydata <- rbind(mydata, cbind(x1,x2,x3))

}
```

After some research, I suspect the bottleneck to be the `rbind()` line. A typical solution is to preallocate the matrix to incorporate the dimensions of the final data. However the reason I can't preallocate the matrix for my purposes is the fact that the output of the API has varying dimensions. I have no idea what the dimensions of my data will be (some API calls return zero rows, while others return 100). How can I make the stacking of the data for each iteration more (time) efficient, especially when the size of `x` and hence the target matrix increases?

Comment: If you're using a `for` loop, doesn't that mean you know how many times to run the loop?  And if you know how many times to run the loop, don't you also know how many rows are in the final data frame?

Comment: @Benjamin  If you run request from API, the output of the request might change from iteration to other.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. I do know how many times the loop runs but (1) some of the API calls are invalid, thus returning no data; and even if the API call is valid, (2) the data returned can be 0 rows in the data, 1,  2 ... up to thousands of rows. Hence, I can never exactly estimate the dimensions of the final matrix.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for clarifying. In that case, might it be possible to assign temporary data frames (or `NULL`s, as appropriate) to hold the data from each iteration and then bind all of the temporary data frames in one call? (ie, use `assign(paste0("temp_df", [i]), cbind(x1, x2, x3))`)  ....  just brainstorming.

Comment: Couldn't you use a `list` instead?

Comment: @Pascal if dynamically updating a list is substantially faster than `rbind()` a matrix, then probably yes. If I understand correctly, this would still require a (slow) `c()` function to combine the chunks, if you have the time, could you submit an example perhaps?

Comment: Could you use a pre-allocated "list" of `length == length(x)` and assign in each element either valid or invalid or absent data depending on each iteration?

Comment: @alexis_laz I actually ended up applying exactly this, then stacking it all with some of the functions from the answer below. It seems really fast and not slowing down when # iterations increases (close to linear time), although I haven't formally benchmarked it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a comparison of some options

Using your current code:

```
x <- 1:10000

system.time({  mydata <- NULL
                for(i in 1:length(x)){
                  y = x[i]
                  x1 = y*2
                  x2 = y*3
                  x3 = y*4
                  mydata <- rbind(mydata, cbind(x1,x2,x3))
                }
              })

   user  system elapsed 
   1.42    0.00    1.42
```

Using a list instead is a bit faster

```
system.time({  mydata_list <- NULL
               for(i in 1:length(x)){
                 y = x[i]
                 x1 = y*2
                 x2 = y*3
                 x3 = y*4
                 mydata_list <- c(mydata_list, list(cbind(x1,x2,x3)))
               }
               mydata_list <- do.call("rbind", mydata_list)
             })

user  system elapsed 
0.42    0.00    0.42
```

And if you assign each iteration's output to an object in a different environment and retrieve them after, you gain yet more time.

```
system.time({  temp_env <- new.env()
               for(i in 1:length(x)){
                 y = x[i]
                 x1 = y*2
                 x2 = y*3
                 x3 = y*4
                 assign(paste0("obj", i), cbind(x1, x2, x3), envir = temp_env)
               }
               mydata_env <- do.call("rbind", 
                                     mget(paste0("obj", 1:length(x)), envir = temp_env))
             })

user  system elapsed 
0.09    0.00    0.09
```

Comment: The performance increase of the example is compelling (thus, I'm accepting this answer). However, I apply method 3 (move to another environment) to my setting and loop 2000 API calls and compare it with method 1 (`rbind` within the loop). The dimensions of the resulting data are 146436 rows and 3 columns. Method 1 takes 718 seconds and Method 3 703 seconds. Although it is faster, this is surprisingly marginal. I'm not sure what's going on. It could be that most probably, ultimately, the latency of the API call is the bottleneck.

Comment: One other possibility is that the dimensions of the data are simply too small for now to notice a substantial difference.

Comment: I'm not completely surprised, although I would have hoped for better.  But our example here is 10,000 loops with smallish data, and it only gained 1.39 seconds.  I know R 3.2 got faster at printing objects by spending less time figuring out what kind of object it was and what method to call.  Perhaps those same optimizations apply to this process as well?  In any case, at this point, it seems like your best hope for speeding this up is to convert your `for` loop into a function and run it through `parallel::parLapply`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I would have hoped for better too given the results from our example. I tried to run the same code but without the `rbind` line, so just for every iteration it extracts the data, does some stuff, but does not store it. Turns out, this is about just as fast as storing it in a list or a temporary environment. Hence, I conclude that with this scale of data of my application (2000 calls), the `rbind` line is not the bottleneck. This is quite surprising given the results here. Perhaps there is a more noticable difference when I scale it up.

Comment: Also, tried different sizes of the loops and it seems to increase close to linear. This is no definite proof, this may change when the loop size is even larger, but it gives some insight in that the storage of the data is not the bottleneck.